# What does the single colon mean in this PHP statement?

Tags: php

It is used for the SlimFramework. The first argument is the router pattern and the second should be a callback. My teacher gave us a class `cdApi` that is inside a `Media` namespace. I understand that the `::class` returns a fully qualified class name resolution, then it is concatenated with THE PART I DON'T UNDERSTAND: `":getOne"`. `getOne` is a function but I never saw the colon used like that, what does it mean?

```
$app->get('/super', \cdApi::class . ':getOne');
```

Comment: It's in quotes, which makes it text.

Comment: but it somehow evaluates to a callback, how?

Comment: That code isn't given here. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: It is a class called "cdApi" with a function called "getOne" inside. Somehow it is provided to the get function, but with that colon, I don't understand how it works, and I couldn't find documentation about that in the PHP manuals nor here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slim framework has a routing feature called "Container Resolution", and that's what you're seeing when you see the single colon. See the slim docs:

https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html

> You are not limited to defining a function for your routes. In Slim
>   there are a few different ways to define your route action functions.
>
> In addition to a function, you may use:
>
> - container_key:method
> - Class:method
> - An invokable class
> - container_key
>
> This functionality is enabled by Slim’s Callable Resolver Class. It
>   translates a string entry into a function call.

Their example:

```
$app->get('/', '\HomeController:home');
```

Answer (score -1):

The double colon is a static method access in PHP

Example static definition:

```
class Foo {
    public static function aStaticMethod() {
        return 'Hello World'
    }
}
```

Which can be called like so:

```
$var = Foo::aStaticMethod()
```

In PHP, the static property 'class' is automatically assigned to any class
(see: http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name)

example:

```
class Foo {}
print Foo::class //prints 'Foo'
```

Comment: but is no double colon, is single colon

Comment: OP's question is about the single colon in the quotes, and OP explains that OP understands the double colon.

Comment: Please read the OP question carefully as he has already stated that he understands the double colon